# NodeJS concurrent requests cause Socket Hang Up Error

Tags: node.js, sockets, concurrency, request

I have started to struggle from a problem a few days ago, after updating my server's software packages.

The problem is that when two requests are made concurrently (two external calls to my API) it returns **"Socket Hang Up" error**.

My API acts like a proxy, it receives requests handles them and send another request to remote server, waits for the response, handles the response and returns some data back.

Here is an example

1. My first request

   ```
   getPublicIpAddressIpify(req, callback) {
   request.get({
       url: 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'
   }).then((response) => {
       if (response) {
           let jsonResult = JSON.parse(response);
           callback.onSuccess(jsonResult['ip']);
       }
       else {
           throw new Error("Cannot determine public ip");
       }
   })
       .catch((error) => {
           callback.onError(error);
       });

    }
   ```
2. My second request

   ```
   getFrontPage(req, callback) {
   request.get({
       resolveWithFullResponse: true,
       url: 'https://google.com'
   }).then((response) => {
       // Handle response
   })
       .catch((error) => {
           callback.onError(error);
       });

    }
   ```

So when these requests are made approximately  at the same time, **Socket Hang UP** is occurred.

Here is debug output

```
{ request: 
   { debugId: 1,
     uri: 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: { host: 'api.ipify.org' } } }
{ response: 
   { debugId: 1,
     headers: 
      { server: 'Cowboy',
        connection: 'close',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        date: 'Sat, 28 Oct 2017 07:29:48 GMT',
        'content-length': '24',
        via: '1.1 vegur' },
     statusCode: 200,
     body: '{"ip":"x.x.x.x"}' } }
{ name: 'User',
  email: 'someuser@gmail.com',
  accountType: 'publisher', }
{ request: 
   { debugId: 2,
     uri: 'https://google.com/',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: 
      { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
        Host: 'www.google.com',
        Origin: 'https://www.google.com',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' } } }
```

This error can be reproduce mostly all the time I try.

I have tested this code on multiple servers, the same error is thrown. 
If I set delay before sending request to `google.com` in this case, it works.

An interesting thing that my API can handle a lot of other requests at the same time, however only this case causes the error.

This worked fine until a system update. I have tried to run `npm update` however this didn't solve the problem.

Also I tried to set global settings for

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;
```

It didn't work either.

Please help to solve this problem, it is really weird and delay before sending second request doesn't work all the time, sometimes it just waits longer and ends up with the same error.

I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Comment: What is the exact error returned?  And, which request does it happen on?  I'm wondering if you have a concurrency design issue elsewhere in the rest of the code that runs when these are called?

Comment: Actually that is not concurrency. These ideally should not affect each other, however it works the other way around. These requests are initiated by the same source, however are quite different. It looks like only one connection is opened and as a result they are clashed

Comment: Do, I asked you a couple questions and you decided not to answer either of them?  Don't think we can help you if you won't answer any questions.